# EasyEDA DRC diameter error

Tags: pcb-design, eda

I'm having a DRC error for the diameter of a trace. The error:

```
Diameter: 0.61mm(24mil)
DRC Diameter: 0.61mm(24.016)mil
```

This has been discussed [here](https://easyeda.com/forum/topic/Via-diameter-DRC-error-ca8a49e573be48739c6c4274a884a64b) and [here](https://easyeda.com/forum/topic/DRC-errors-after-switching-from-mm-to-mils-218bf4c10fd84409a5ee83ca0277fb0d) with only a "we will improve this issue" message from EasyEDA. Other users are still running into this.

How do I resolve the issue? I have it with all my via's. Where do i need to go in the menu and what do i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a good solution if you have a lot of errors but you need to:

1. Right click where the error is
2. Go to Attributes
3. Add a bunch of zeros at the end of the Diameter property to remove the rounding error.

Pics below.

See 21 DRC errors
[image]

Right click where error is and go to attributes
[image]

Add zeros at end of the Diameter to remove rounding error
[image]

Only 20 errors now after updating and refreshing DRC errors (green icon next to folder)
[image]

Comment: There *is* an easy solution. Namely using the intended Design Rule setting offered by EasyEDA.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy solution:**

In PCB View: go to "Design" -> "Design Rule..."

Set the Default Via Diameter a bit smaller, e.g. to 0.6 mm or 23 mil.

This will *not* change the Default specs of new vias you place (or of existing vias), but it changes the via Design Rule minimum diameter for Default nets. If this design rule is lower than your actual via dimensions, you get no DRC error.